# place objects on more than one cell in a grid based game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to create a grid based game with Unity. I generate the grid with this sample code

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) 
 {
     for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) 
     {
         Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3 (x, 0, z), cubePrefab.transform.rotation);
     }
 }
```

I read the grid information from a file. The problem is that this code only works for objects having a size (width and length) of 1 cell. It might be that there are objects bigger than one cell.

Example 1: The wooden benches

[image: wooden benches]

Example 2: The flower pots

[image: flower pots]

How would you generate your map then?

The first approach coming to my mind would be to connect the cells to a group. Whenever the player tries to move to or interact with a cell of this group, the group runs the logic. This could be a collision (player can't move here) or a trap (player dies on each group cell).

But the second problem is, how would you place your models then? When generating an external level file, the data has to know that the model has to get stretched along with multiple cells...

Comment: You can create "dummy" tiles, which point to the main tile of a multi-tile object. [Reference here.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70564/representing-multi-tile-objects-in-a-tilemap) For drawing, the dummy tiles can pass their location to the main tile which can handle it accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-tile objects on tiled map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307668/multi-tile-objects-on-tiled-map)